# Task Parallelism (TPL) and Task Scheduling in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

According to Microsoft ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)), there are two ways to start a task: **Implicit** and **Explicit**.

Assume that I created 4 different tasks in main thread called task1, task2, task3 and task4.

**case1**: I run them all, explicitly in main thread:

```
task1.Start();
task2.Start();
task3.Start();
task4.Start();
```

**case2**: I run them implicitly using Parallel.Invoke method in main thread:

```
Parallel.Invoke(task1, task2, task3, task4);
```

The only difference I noticed is that in case2, the main thread suspends until Invoke( ) returns.

My question is about the *Task scheduler*. 
Does the task scheduler behave 4 tasks in case1 and case2 differently in terms of scheduling or they are completely equivalent ?

in the same link I have mentioned above we read:

> Behind the scenes, tasks are queued to the ThreadPool, which has been
>   enhanced with algorithms (like hill-climbing) that determine and
>   adjust to the number of threads that maximizes throughput. This makes
>   tasks relatively lightweight, and you can create many of them to
>   enable fine-grained parallelism. To complement this, widely-known
>   work-stealing algorithms are employed to provide load-balancing.

Comment: Is this curiosity or do you have some code that depends on this information?

Comment: Yes. its out of curiosity. I did not find any reference for this so i decided to post this to see if anyone can give me a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/07/10/9828076.aspx) from the Parallel team should answer some of your questions.

Short answer: with Tasks you will have to do a Task::WaitAll(...) on your main thread to prevent from exiting where as Parallel::Invoke will actually take care of this for you. Beyond that, nothing else because the same TPL infrastructure is used under Parallel::Invoke.

Comment: Yes. Because threads of Tasks are background, we must block the main thread (by using WaitAll for example) and wait for them to be completed, Otherwise they will be terminated abruptly.
and I agree, The same TPL infrastructure is used under Invoke. This is apparent from this picture:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5153771/ParallelProgramming.png.
but does it means that they are equivalent in terms of scheduling ? Thanks u for the answer and the great blog post.

Comment: The same task scheduler is used in both cases